# Merging arrays to form a list of items with duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Currently i have some code as follows:

```
let ingrediantsResults = [
    {
        dinnerName: "Vegetable Soup",
        ingrediants: ["potatoes", "onion", "spring onion", "lentils", "beans", "turnip" ]
    },
    {
        dinnerName: "Spaghetti",
        ingrediants: ["spaghetti pasta", "tomato box", "onion", "sundried tomatoes", "tomato paste", "lentils"]
    }
];

var reducedArray = ingrediantsResults.reduce((acc,item) => {
    var previousItem = acc.find(findItem => findItem.dinnerName === item.dinnerName);
    if(!previousItem){
      acc.push({...item, quantity: 1})
    }else{
       previousItem.quantity++
    }
    return acc;
  },[]);
  
  console.log(reducedArray);
```

in this example im struggling to find a way to create a new array with the combination of all ingrediants in. Also i wonder if it is possible to "IF" there is a duplicate item, in this case "onion" is listed twice, that it is presented in some way?

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: You can use destructuring.  To merge two arrays without duplicates, you can do like this: const array3 = [...array1, ...array2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'combination of all ingredients' (NB. note spelling) sounds like a union operation on the ingredients of each object, and so duplicates are removed. You could do that with lodash (_.uniq), or you could do it with a `Set`, converted into an array:

```
[...new Set([].concat(...ingrediantsResults.map(obj => obj.ingrediants)))]
```

If you want duplicates to be represented "in some way", I take it you don't mean to just leave them there, but to count them. You'd end up with a dictionary where the keys are ingredients and the values are integer counts. Again, lodash has a thing for that (_.count or _.countBy). Or, to avoid the dependency:

```js
let ingrediantsResults = [
  {
      dinnerName: "Vegetable Soup",
      ingrediants: ["potatoes", "onion", "spring onion", "lentils", "beans", "turnip" ]
  },
  {
      dinnerName: "Spaghetti",
      ingrediants: ["spaghetti pasta", "tomato box", "onion", "sundried tomatoes", "tomato paste", "lentils"]
  }]

const allIngredients = [].concat(...ingrediantsResults.map(obj => obj.ingrediants))

console.log(allIngredients.reduce((acc, item) => {
    acc[item] = (acc[item] || 0) + 1
    return acc
}, {}))
```